# Reversing a multiplication in 64 bit arithmetic

Tags: python, integer, 64-bit, division, multiplication

I'm trying to do some multiplications and divisions with 64 bit integers. I want my results to have 64 bit, any overflow should be truncated. I've managed to get it working with multiplications:

```
z = 0xed5c6911
y = 0xFFFFFFFF & (z * 33)

print hex(z)
print hex(y)
```

This outputs:

```
0xed5c6911
0x98e98b31
```

as expected.

I would like to reverse this now:

```
z = 0xFFFFFFFF & (y / 33)
print hex(z)
```

I would expect `0xed5c6911`, the original value of `z`, but I am getting `0x4a23a85`.

**How can I reverse the operation done in the first snippet and retrieve the original value of `z` from `y`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update:** after comment by [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045): your mask is only 32 bit - in oder to mask 64 bit you'd need to mask all your integers with `& 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

all that follows is for **32-bit**:

it *is* possible to reverse the operation: by truncating to 32 bits you are effectively doing calculations in the integer ring `Z/2^32 Z`. 33 does have a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) in there:

```
1/33 = 0x3e0f83e1  mod  2^32
```

so for *any* 32-bit number you can reverse the multiplication by 33 by multipliying with the number above (and truncating to 32-bit).

you would find the inverse by using the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). mathematically this in the domain of [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory).

note that only the odd numbers in this ring have an inverse (2 is the only prime factor of 2^32).

for **64 bit** the inverse of 33 is:

```
1/33 = 0x0f83e0f83e0f83e1  mod  2^64
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I'm not sure how to interpret that. How can I implement it in Python?

Comment: sure! the pseudo-code on wikipedia is close to python; otherwise try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519535/extended-euclidean-algorithm-and-the-concept-of-multiplicative-inverse

Comment: Isn't it Z/2^32Z though? Because of the masking?

Comment: you are correct! this `FF` sequence seemed awfully short! oh. i'll have to check out your blog!

Answer (score 0):

This operation is irreversible. When you multiply `z` by 33, you're pushing the uppermost 64th bit over the 64 bit limit and destroying information by overflowing.

You can see the value of 0xed5c6911 in binary [using google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=0xed5c6911%20in%20binary).

In other words, you need to use a datatype that's wider than 64 bits to perform this operation. For instance, you can use `long`:

```
z = long(0xed5c6911)
y = long(0xFFFFFFFFFFFF) & (z * 33) # Note the added F's
print hex(z)  # 0xed5c6911L
print hex(y)  # 0x1e98e98b31L
```

Using `long` you can reverse this operation:

```
z = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF & (y / 33) # Again, note the added F's
print hex(z) # 0xed5c6911L
```

Comment: No information is lost on multiplication by 33 (or any other odd number); see @hiro-protagonist's answer.

Answer (score -2):

You won't be able to retrieve the original value of z from y.

When you truncate the multiplication of (z * 33) in your first example, you are losing information - in this case the upper bits. Then when you do the division, you are dividing a different value then (z * 33) and therefore wont be able to recover z.

In order to actually get z back, you need to store some additional information - the easiest way is by using a data type with more bits.

Comment: No information is lost on multiplication by 33 (or any other odd number); see @hiro-protagonist's answer.